# How can I get a List of All Tags to have no pagination by default?

Tags: tags, pagination

When I make a list of all tags, it breaks the list into chunks of 20 for pagination by default. I want the default to be "all", ideally without the selector.

**How can I make a list of all tags show *all of the tags*, without any pagination?**

Answer (score 4):

Go to the menu that includes the list of all tags, then open up the page you created as a list of all tags. There should be a menu tab called "selection options". Set "Display Select", "Pagination" and "Pagination Results" to "Hide".